# Assignment to write a program that gives the user a choice between two options - C

Tags: c, function

I have an assignment due and I am drawing a blank on what exactly to do... I'm sure it is simple but I havent quite gotten the hang of things yet. The assignment is  -

Write a program that gives the user 2 menu options: either call a function that will print a greeting and your name 4 times or call a function that will count down from 10 to 0 and then print "Blastoff!". Both functions should use for loops to print the appropriate output.

I have the prompt and the functions done so far... but I am unsure of how to display one or the other depending on the choice the user makes. Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
// declare counter variable
int i;


// prompt the user to make a choice
    printf("What would you like to do?\n  1. Print my name\n  2. Count down from 10\n");    
    printf("\n");

// display greeting and name 4 times
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("Hi, my name is Bridget\n");
    }


// display countdown
    for(i=10;i>=0;--i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
        printf("Blastoff!");





}
```

Comment: You will need to `scanf` for the user input, and based on that input, `if(userInput == 1)`, call the function that corresponds to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use Switch case.

```
    switch(choice) {
     case 1: //first for loop
     break;
     case 2: //second for loop
     break;
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. 
Thank you very much. Everything is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

You should read the input from user's keyboard:

```
int c;
c = getchar();
if (c == '1')
{
// display greeting and name 4 times
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
    printf("Hi, my name is Bridget\n");
}
}
if (c == '2')
{
// display countdown
for(i=10;i>=0;--i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
}
printf("Blastoff!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a couple of points here. Firstly, you have not yet written any functions. Try looking [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm) to gain some insight on that front.

Secondly, to make a choice based on user input you need to actually get that input somehow. You'll probably want to use [scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm).

Lastly, once you have the user's input (say, in a variable declared as `int input;`) you can use [if](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/if_else_statement_in_c.htm) to control the flow of your program based on that variable like this:

```
if(input == 1){
    greet();
}
else {
    countDown();
}
```

Cheers! If you have any further questions feel free to comment below.

Comment: Thank you! That line was very helpful.

Comment: @MissAnnThropic I'm glad. Still, you should implement the functions like I and other suggested or you're not going to get full credit :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you haven't actually declared you functions. Functions in C should be declared like the `main` function is. For more info in this see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm).

```
// display greeting and name 4 times
void greeting(){
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("Hi, my name is Bridget\n");
    }
}

void countdown() {
// display countdown
    for(i=10;i>=0;--i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
        printf("Blastoff!");
}
```

To get the user's input the most common way is by keyboard. `scanf` accomplishes that in C. Details on `scanf` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

```
int main(void){
  int i, choice;

  //prompt the user to make a choice
  // You don't need 2 printf for the newlines stick them to one.
  printf("What would you like to do?\n  1. Print my name\n  2. Count down from 10\n\n");

  //This takes the user's input and puts it in the variable choice
  scanf(%d, &choice);
}
```

Lastly to decide what to do based on the user input you can use either an `if then else` statement or a `switch`. I will provide a solution with an `if` statement and you can figure the one with the `switch` on your own. Your final code should look like this.

```
int main(void){
    int i, choice;

    //prompt the user to make a choice
    // You don't need 2 printf for the newlines stick them to one.
    printf("What would you like to do?\n  1. Print my name\n  2. Count down from 10\n\n");

    //This takes the user's input and puts it in the variable choice
    scanf(%d, &choice);

    if(choice == 1){
      greeting();
    }else{
      countdown();
    }
}

// display greeting and name 4 times
void greeting(){
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("Hi, my name is Bridget\n");
    }
}

void countdown() {
// display countdown
    for(i=10;i>=0;--i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
        printf("Blastoff!");
}
```

Bear in mind that this code has a lot of flaws (error checking mainly) but I guess your assigment is not about that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to include libraries with function you will need. You do this by

```
#include <someLibrary.h>
```

at the beggining of you document. Libraries mostly have .h extension. Always look for them if you try to do something. You consider them to have best performance and functionality as possible (not always true).

What is next you declare your functions. Function has name, arguments which are going into it, body in which they do something and return value (can be float, int, char etc). If function doesnt return anything, they return void (dont have ***return*** at the end). You declare functions before ***main()*** with only types of arguments. Whole body is after main (it is better looking).

If you declared function with arguments, you have to provide these arguments to function in () brackets. Even if no arguments are needed, you use them like ***getch()*** in example below. Note that function become what it return. If you declared some new variables in function they will be visible only in function. On the other hand function will not see any variable from other function (main too). If you want so, declare global variables (not recommended).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>  //libraries

void function1(int);
float function2(float);  //declaration of functions

int main()
{   
char decision;
printf("press 'a' to run function1, press 'b' to run function2\n");
decision=getch();     //first see getch()? look in google for functionality and library !
    int someInt=10;
    float someFloat=11;

     if(decision== 'a')
    {
     function1(someInt);
    }
    else if(decision == 'b')
    {
     printf("%f", funcion2(someFloat));  //example that function become what    they return
    }
    else 
    {
     printf("No decision has been made");
    }
getch();   //program will wait for any key press
return 0;
}

void function1(int param1)
{
  //print your stuff               // this function return void, so doesnt have return; statement
} 
float function2(float param1)
{
 return 2*param1;                 //this function have to return some float
}
```